# Is there a method to highlight the order of edges according to ID in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphviz

I am having a GV file (`Final_Graph.gv`) like this:

```
digraph Final_Graph {
    graph [center=true rankdir=LR ratio=compress size="15,10"]
    a
    b
    c
    d
    a -> b [label = 1 id=1]
    a -> c [label = 2 id=2]
    a -> d [label = 3 id=3]
    b -> d [label = 4 id=4]
    c -> d [label = 5 id=5]

    subgraph cluster_1{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="A"
        a
        b
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_2{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="B"
        a
        b
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_3{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="C"
        c
        d
    }
}


function renderString(str){
    graphviz.tweenShapes(false)
    .renderDot(str);
    
}

function render() {
fetch('Final_Graph.gv').then(response  => response.text()).then(textAsString => 
     renderString(textAsString));
}
```

[image: rendered GV]

I have written my code in D3.js so that each of the edges would be highlighted (change color to red) according to its ID, so a->b would be highlighted first with id=1, followed up by a->c (id=2), and so on.

Here is my current code in D3 (Please note that my code is in D3 v5, so I am not sure that this code could be compatible with the newer versions):

```
let graphviz = d3.select(".graph").graphviz()
.transition(function () {
    return d3.transition("main")
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .delay(500)
        .duration(1500);}
)
.logEvents(true)
.on("initEnd", render)
.on("end", function() {
    
    d3.selectAll("g.edge").sort(function(a,b){ // Set up edges.
        return a["id"] - b["id"];
    });
    let link = d3.selectAll("path");
    
    link.each(function(d, i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            
            d3.select(link.nodes()[i]).transition().style("stroke", "red");
        }, i * 1000);
    })
});
```

However when I load the website, the edges are not highlighted in ascending order as my idea; instead the highlighting order is 5->1->2->3->4. I have checked in my console and adding ID for nodes, as well as rearranging nodes according to ID; however that also did not solve the problem.

So is there any method to make edges in this graph highlighted with ID from 1 to 5 as I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that

```
div
  .selectAll(".edge")
  .nodes()
  .forEach(...)
```

should iterate through the edges in the order in which they were laid down so there should be no need to sort. Taking that into account, here's some code that animates the drawing of the edges in response to a button push:

```js
let source = `digraph Final_Graph {
  graph [center=true rankdir=LR ratio=compress size="15,10"]
  a
  b
  c
  d
  a -> b [label = 1 id=1]
  a -> c [label = 2 id=2]
  a -> d [label = 3 id=3]
  b -> d [label = 4 id=4]
  c -> d [label = 5 id=5]
  subgraph cluster_1{
color=lightgrey style=filled
label="A"
a
b
  }
  subgraph cluster_2{
color=lightgrey style=filled
label="B"
a
b
  }
  subgraph cluster_3{
color=lightgrey style=filled
label="C"
c
d
  }
}`;

let div = d3.select("#graph")
div.graphviz().renderDot(source, function() {
  div.selectAll("title").remove();
  div.selectAll("text").style("pointer-events", "none");
})
d3.select('#button').on('click', draw_edges)


function draw_edges() {
  div
.selectAll(".edge")
.nodes()
.forEach(function (e, i) {
  let ee = d3.select(e);
  let path = ee.select("path");
  let length = path.node().getTotalLength();
  path.attr("stroke-dasharray", [0, length]);
  let head = ee.select("polygon");
  head.attr("opacity", 0);
  setTimeout(() => {
    path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", [0, length])
      .transition()
      .duration(400)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", [length, length]);
    setTimeout(() => head.attr("opacity", 1), 400);
  }, 400 * (i + 1));
});
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.11/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@3.0.5/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>

<button id="button">Draw edges</button>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

I think the motion captures the users attention much better than the coloring.

I've also [implemented this using Observable](https://observablehq.com/d/ddb320618d36b8fe) and you can see code for animating the process using color there as well.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas Mark! However when I am running your code, I got one error of ```TypeError: d3.graphviz is not a function```, although my code in the past with ```d3.select('.graph').graphviz``` does not have this problem. So did you download any other module for D3-Graphviz, or you just mentioned the website for this library in ```<script>```?

Comment: Also, I tried to create ```div``` for my website in D3 v5, and D3 could not create the ```div```, so I use ```d3.selectAll('.edge).nodes().forEach(...) ``` and couldn't get the edges to highlight in the right order.

Comment: There are evidently some differences between [this version of d3Graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz) and the one used on Observable. I've updated my answer to a form that hopefully helps.